# php or javascript textfile semicolon db using one record to display another on hover

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, flat-file

Here's what I got... Been searching forums but did not find anything that I could help me in this situation... Here is a  [screenshot](http://galzerano.com/server.png), I'm looking at the jobstatus panel on the right and want to show my record in the header.

I started swimming waste deep in this water and now it's over my head...

*My situation...*

Here is my jquery code to highlight a row....

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$("tr").not(':first').hover( 
function () { 
$(this).css("background","#d3d3d3"); 
}, 
function () { 
$(this).css("background",""); 
} 
); 

</script>
```

When it hovers I want to show a record in the header when you hover over a row in the table.
I've been using php to do this so far but I'm not sure if php is the best thing for this.

Here is my php to grab the records and create the table....

```
<?php 

$row = 1; 
if (($handle = fopen($statfile, "r")) !== FALSE) { 

echo '<table class="sortable" border="0">'; 

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) { 
    if (substr($data[0],0,3)!='HDR' && substr($data[0],0,3) != 'JOB' )       continue; 
    $num = count($data); 
    if (substr($data[0],0,3)=='HDR') { 
        echo '<thead><tr>'; 
    }else{ 
        echo '<tr>'; 
    } 
    for ($c=1; $c <= 4; $c++) { 
        //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n"; 
        if(empty($data[$c])) { 
           $value = "&nbsp;"; 
        }else{ 
           $value = trim($data[$c]); 
        } 
    if (substr($data[0],0,3)=='HDR') { 
            echo '<th style="text-align:center">'.$value."</th>\n"; 
        }else{ 
            if ($c==1) { 
            echo '<td style="text-align:center"><a href="http://wfbscd13/cgi-  bin/aplog.cgi?type=job&logname='.$value.'&hostname='.$host.'">'.$value."</a>   </td>\n"; 

            }else{ 
            echo '<td style="text-align:center">'.$value."</td>\n"; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    if (substr($data[0],0,3)=='HDR') { 
        echo '</tr></thead><tbody>'; 
    }else{ 
        echo '</tr>'; 
    } 
    $row++; 
} 

echo '</tbody></table>'; 
fclose($handle); 
} 
?>
```

So far everything works it displays my info in the table, the sortable class sorts it...

```
PWR 9 ; #00FF00 ; 
PWR 10 ; #00FF00 ; 
PWR 11 ; #FF0000 ; 
HDR 0 ; Session ; User ; Domains ; E-Time ; Host ; Design ; Path ; 
JOB 1 ; 122:1 ; hupcey ; 6 ; 00:22:42 ; 158.140.43.151 ;         ixdiag_model_bedb ; /home/hupcey/diags 
JOB 2 ; 121:1 ; galzerano ; 2 ; 00:10:42 ; 158.140.43.151 ;         ixdiag_model_bedb ; /home/hupcey/diags
```

I'm in the JOB index and I want the IP to show up when you hover over the row...

Am I barking up the right tree? 
Can someone help me or point  a finger? I appreciate any help on this matter.

William

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax. Build a query to get data from database to be called using ajax. Then use the result to update the 'status'